# Extracting values from a Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below pandas object from which I am trying to extract value corresponding to each key.

```
{'attributes': {'type': 'Contact', 'url': '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact/0035B00000KRMhZQAX'}, 'Id': '0035B00000KRMhZQAX', 'Name': 'abc xyz', 'Id': 'hello00'}
```

Expected output:

```
Id : 0035B00000KRMhZQAX
Name : abc xyz
CustId : hello00
```

**Edited input value:**

```
{'attributes': {'type': 'Contact', 'url': '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact/0035B00000KRMhZQAX'}, 'Id': '0035B00000KRMhZQAX', 'Name': 'abc xyz', 'CustId': 'hello00'}
```

Comment: @Nihal, updated the dictionary in my original message

Comment: What is print `df.head().to_dict()` ? There are multiple `Id` ?

Comment: @jezrael, I get the below output

{'col': {0: {'attributes': {'type': 'Contact',
    'url': '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact/0035B00000KRMhZQAX'},
   'Id': '0035B00000KRMhZQAX',
   'Name': 'abc xyz',
   'Id': 'hello00'}}}

Comment: @jezrael, currently I just have one entry in this object and hence only one id is returned..

Comment: I think `'Id': '0035B00000KRMhZQAX',` and `'Id': 'hello00'`

Comment: @jezrael, this is the output I received when I did df.head().to_dict()

{'col': {0: {'attributes': {'type': 'Contact', 'url': '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact/0035B00000KRMhZQAX'}, 'Id': '0035B00000KRMhZQAX', 'Name': 'abc xyz', 'Id': 'hello00'}}}

Comment: 'Id' in the input and 'ID' in the output are different, please provide more details.

Comment: @jezrael, sorry just realized I mis-typed CustId as Id, have updated the initial post with the updated input value

Comment: @Yogesh, sorry have got the input value updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'col': {0: {'attributes': {'type': 'Contact', 'url': '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact/0035B00000KRMhZQAX'},
                                'Id': '0035B00000KRMhZQAX', 'Name': 'abc xyz', 'CustId': 'hello00'}}} )
df.loc[1, 'col'] = 10
df.loc[2, 'col'] = np.nan
```

---

```
print (df)
                                                 col
0  {'attributes': {'type': 'Contact', 'url': '/se...
1                                                 10
2                                                NaN
```

First filter only values with dictionaries:

```
df = df[df['col'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, dict))]
print (df)
                                                 col
0  {'attributes': {'type': 'Contact', 'url': '/se...
```

Exctract by keys, if key not exist add `None`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(x.get('Id', None), x.get('Name', None), x.get('CustId', None)) 
                    for x in df['col']], columns=['Id','Name','CustId'])
print (df1)
                   Id     Name   CustId
0  0035B00000KRMhZQAX  abc xyz  hello00
```

Comment: Thanks, this threw another error 
     "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: @darkhorse - If still error, it means in some row in something different like this dictionary. Can you check it?

Comment: updated as mentioned. However this throws an error "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: @darkhorse - Are real data confidental?

Comment: yes there is some confidential data. I was able to work past this by doing the below:

df_new = pd.DataFrame(Contact).drop('attributes', axis= 1, inplace=False)..

Thanks for your help as always..